# How to access sqlite from php script in tidesdk

Tags: php, tidesdk

I am having a little challenge and  I hope you can help me with. First I've read the tidesdk documentations
over and over. I searched stackoverflow for help. No help. The problem is

After navigating to a .php file from the index.html, I echo "test" in my php file with the . It works
fine. All php stuffs works fine. Only one thing doesn't work.
sqlite_query("some statement") ; return the error, 'call to undefined
function' . I check the sqlite extension in the php module of tide and it's enabled.
The code works as expected in a regular Web server. Everything works great
except working with my own sqlite file.

Any help?